# PayPal webhooks don't work

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-webhooks

There are two problems with PayPal webhooks.

The First.

I've created REST app on Sandbox, added webhook and got successful message. Then refreshed page and webhooks list became empty. Tried to add it again and got error message:

```
Webhook URL already exists
```

The Second.

I tried to test hook with simulator and got:

```
Your event has been successfully queued at August 28 2015, 0:33:29
```

but nothing was sent to my server. The same result is in case of successful purchases through Sandbox API  - no calls.

Actually I'm not sure if webhook should be called for payments between two personal accounts (not merchant accounts) and also on paying invoices (created through API) via PayPal site. It should I guess but can't figure out the cause why it doesn't work.

I've read all documentations about webhooks and invoices and found nothing helpful concerning the problem. If IPN can be the solution? An what the difference between IPN and Wehbooks?

P.S. SSL certificate for wehbook URL is self-signed but anyway making some request manually I can see in server's log that request was made.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that you ran in to an issue with PayPal Webhooks. Here is some information and update on the problems you've faced.

1. The first problem is fixed.
2. Regarding second, can you please elaborate on the "Webhooks for payments between personal accounts"?

   Webhooks for Invoices are currently not supported but they are coming very  soon.

Usha